# Merge tags [knr] and [kr-c]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I came across tags [knr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/knr) (51 questions) and [kr-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kr-c)(33 questions), and 3 questions are tagged with both.

Wiki entries:

- [knr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/knr) *Questions about or related to the book "The C Programming Language" (which is also known as K&R) by Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie.*
- [kr-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kr-c) *For questions about the C language described in Kernighan & Ritchie "The C Programming Language", and possibly for questions about pre-standard C.*

There doesn't seem to be much doubt that they're basically the same tag.

#### Questions

1. Which tag should be kept?
2. Should the other be made a synonym, or simply eliminated?
3. Is the migration something the Stack Overflow team would handle or is it something that we're going to have to handle with brute force and tedious updates?

My inclination is to prefer [knr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/knr) over [kr-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kr-c) (and not just because of the relative numbers of questions); another option might be [k-and-r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/k-and-r).

I'm contemplating creating a tag such as [knr-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/knr-functions) to cover questions about K&R-style function definitions, and was researching what tags are already available before doing so.

---

#### Meta Stack Exchange

There's a closed question on MSE that's closely related:

- [Tag synonym request: ([kernighan-and-ritchie] and [kr-c]) -> [knr]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110829/tag-synonym-request-kernighan-and-ritchie-and-kr-c-knr)

Comment: I don't really like `knr`; it looks too much like an acronym.

Comment: There was once a question by me about making [knr] and [kr-c] synonyms or merging them, and in the end it was rejected for cause: [knr] is about the book (also more modern revisions) while [kr-c] is about the language.

Comment: More interestingly, there is a [kernighan-and-ritchie](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kernighan-and-ritchie) tag.  That probably needs to be distributed amoung [knr] and [kr-c].

Comment: IMO, all 3 tags should be merged into one. Frankly, there's no reason to separate pre-standard C and K&R C book (they are both the same and K&R C book was the *Standard* in the pre-standard era!).

Comment: @BlueMoon: Seems you should read my answer: The book is not about K&R-C, at least the second revision isn't.

Comment: @Deduplicator I read your answer before posting my comment. While version 2 covers almost all of C89, the book came out *before* C89 was ratified. Even if it covers, entire C89, its tag should just be C rather than K-R-C (version 2). The term *ANSI C* has been outdated and has no good meaning now. So to say K&R version 2 covers ANSI C could be misleading today and the book doesn't claim to be C89 (or ANSI C -- that you are referring to as) conformant.

Comment: Looking back at some old ignored synonym/retag requests and I see this one. Looks like [tag:knr] is long gone, so no need for anything there. (Good riddance, I say; I don't like 'n' for 'and'.) Before I tag this as [status-completed], what are your thoughts on P.P.'s proposal to merge [tag:kernighan-and-ritchie] and [tag:kr-c]? It seems reasonable to me; in modern times and in practice, it doesn't seem like the book vs. the pre-standard language spec is a useful distinction.

Comment: @CodyGray: I'd be happy to see [tag:kr-c] merged with [tag:kernighan-and-ritchie] — the latter, longer name is much easier to understand.  I'd prefer [tag:k&r] but I assume that isn't an option.  The only (mild) downside might be the distinction between ANSI C as used in K&R 2nd Edn and the K&R C language as it existed before ANSI C (using ANSI C for C89 — ISO for C90, C99, C11).  On the whole, that isn't enough of a loss to be a problem.  There are about 37 [tag:kr-c] and 227 [tag:kernighan-and-ritchie] questions when I checked just now.  Unless we decided on [tag:pre-standard-c]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, the tags [knr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/knr), [kr-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kr-c) and [kernighan-and-ritchie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kernighan-and-ritchie) should be merged into a single tag (whichever is deemed more appropriate).

Basically, there should be only a single tag that covers pre-standard C (including K&R book).
If it's about standardized C then [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) should be used. If the question is about specific standard of C then the respective tag ([c89](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c89), [c99](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c99) or [c11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c11)) can be used alongside [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c).

Besides, these ([knr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/knr), [kr-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kr-c) and [kernighan-and-ritchie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kernighan-and-ritchie)) are mostly used in questions about the exercises mentioned in K&R book (version 2) rather than anything specific to pre-standard C (before C89).

There have only been a handful of questions that use these tags (53, 33 and 93 respectively) in the entire existence of SO while there have been many questions asked about K&R book everyday, which suggests these tags are not really working. Because it's not intuitive for someone to think that there could be a tag specific to K&R book (even if it's *the* book) and usually everyone mentions it in the title or body of the question (That's much better for google search than these tags by the way).

Imagine yourself as a new user asking about a C question and you are familiar with K&R book. Would you naturally look for [knr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/knr) or [kernighan-and-ritchie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kernighan-and-ritchie) in the tags field while tagging?

While the community can encourage/edit questions to add these tags (if it's not tagged by askers), I don't see any reason to religiously make these tags *work*, if these tags are not working already.

Comment: Going by daily evidence, as a new user I would just ask my question and not look, and try to duplicate my title in the tag-field.

Comment: I completely agree with this answer, the three tags are used for the very same purposes. It is either questions regarding the book, or (far less frequently) questions regarding pre-standard C. Which of the 3 tags that gets picked seems arbitrary. I think we can keep kr-c and kernighan-and-ritchie, then nuke "knr". I have never heard the term "knr" used. The ideal tag would of course be "K&R" but the ampersand can apparently not be used in tag names.

Comment: Implemented as described in this answer, after 3 top users of that tag (OP, Answerer and @Lundin) have agreed to the same.

Answer (score 2):

They should not be merged:

[knr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/knr) Is about **the book** "The C Progamming Language" by K&R, in both revisions:

- Version 1: K&R C
- Version 2: ANSI C

[kr-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kr-c) is about **the language pre-ANSI**, as described in the first revision.

<sup>If I could still find a link to my old and mis-guided question (requesting merge and/or synonymization), I would link it here.

Oh well, on the dustheap of history it stays.</sup>

Summary: While it might make sense to kill [knr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/knr) (and probably also [kernighan-and-ritchie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kernighan-and-ritchie)) for being meta-tags, certainly not all of them deal in K&R-C, which is a version of C and thus deserving of its own tag.

Comment: The three wikis says otherwise. Did you read them? More so, the tags are not used in the way you claim that they should be used.

Comment: @Lundin: You might want to re-read them.