# Is [kernighan-and-ritchie] a valid tag on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm aware the K&R C is a fairly prevalent C standard, but should [kernighan-and-ritchie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kernighan-and-ritchie) be a valid tag given that a lot of the questions that use the tag pertain to a specific book?

What is Stack Overflow's policy about book specific tags?

Comment: All I can really do right now is grumble.  I don't think it belongs here but I'm not sure if removing it is smart right now.  They're asking questions about solutions they see in the book, which I *guess* is okay, but I wish there was a better way to go about this.

Comment: K&R was the C standard before C89 was released, a standard set by the book.  Questions about code in the book ought to be tagged that way, given that it is not C89-compliant.  It is still pretty popular today.  Very healthy tag, 95% of all questions got answered.

Comment: @HansPassant I think it is a good idea to include this into tag info then

Comment: @HansPassant There is another tag:[tag:kr-c] for that.

Comment: @Oleg That one should maybe be a synonym of the other then, or vice versa.

Comment: Personally - although nobody agrees with me! - I'm totally fine with questions about books (or e.g. popular online tutorial series) existing. It seems that they describe topics where it's far *more* possible to have genuine "expertise" than most tags on Stack Overflow. Years of Python experience don't come close to meaning that I know the answer to every Python question, but if somebody asks "How do I avoid overfrobnicating the widget in Problem 1.3.4 in *Fooscript++ for Beginners*", and I've solved all the problems in that book, then that's *perfectly* suited for me to answer.

Comment: @HansPassant Regarding the health of the tag, I think that's mostly because it isn't normally a tag that the OP adds by their own initiative, but rather something edited in by veteran [tag:C] users. Which is of course perfectly fine.

Comment: The formal policy regarding books, as set by the Stack Overflow company is: we love to have lots of information about books all over! Bad books, good books, trash books! Anything that generates site traffic is lovely! [See this as proof](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295460/delete-the-list-of-random-books), where SO employees mangled the decisions of (user-elected) diamond mods and the community. I hear next up in the road map is cute cat pictures and porn.

Comment: @MarkAmery While answering questions that are triggered by a certain book is certainly not a bad thing, that doesn't mean we need tags for each and every programming book ever.

Answer (score 16):

Yes it is a valid tag. The tag is for code and examples from the K&R book, which is (unfortunately) frequently used by beginners still to this day. We created [kernighan-and-ritchie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kernighan-and-ritchie) exclusively for questions regarding the examples in the book.

One use for the tag is to explain why the code in the question is strange -  because it is a copy/paste from an obsolete book, rather than the OP being bad. So the tag is rather similar to [language-lawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) in a way, as it is used to show that the code is artificial and badly written for a reason.

This is not to be confused with questions regarding pre-standard C, which should use [kr-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kr-c). (And those question are rare)

There's a meta discussion about it [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272606/merge-tags-knr-and-kr-c). Which I believe lead to burnination of [knr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/knr). [kernighan-and-ritchie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kernighan-and-ritchie) is supposedly the replacement for that bad tag.

This is all explained in the [kr-c tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/kr-c/info) and the [kernighan-and-ritchie tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/kernighan-and-ritchie/info) respectively.

**EDIT**

I assumed that everyone participating in the discussion actually have a clue about the topic, but apparently not...

This book acted as industry de facto standard for the C language during the years 1972 to 1989, before a formal standardization was available. So it is not just any random book, it is intimately connected to the language specification itself, with the inventor of the language as co-author. As such, it is absolutely on-topic.

Comment: *"We created kernighan-and-ritchie exclusively for questions regarding the examples in the book."* - note that other tags meant to group together problems from a particular problem set (like the `ruby-koans` tag, which I used to have favorited) have been [burninated en masse](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284302/1709587) in the past, to my dismay. You say it's a "valid tag", but I fear the community and the mods may disagree, especially given the purpose you've stated for its existence.

Comment: @MarkAmery This book is special though, since it actually acted as the language standard for over 15 years. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17206568/what-is-the-difference-between-c-c99-ansi-c-and-gnu-c/17209532#17209532). You can't compare it with some generic "puzzle/competition tags".

Comment: I'm well aware of the significance of the book; the implication in your edit that I don't *"have a clue about the topic"* is wrong. Yet per your own description of the tags, `kr-c` is about the pre-standard C language-as-informally-standardised-by-K&R (analogous to, say, the `c99` tag), and `kernighan-and-richie` is simply about the contents of the book in its own right, not as interpreted as a standard (surely analogous to any other tag about a famous programming book?). It's the latter tag whose survival is at stake, not the former, and it's unclear to me that *that* is a special case.

Comment: Also, it's missing the point to argue that questions about the book are "absolutely on topic". Programming questions taken from any competition site are like "on topic" too; that's wholly orthogonal to whether they should have a *tag*.

Comment: @MarkAmery A programming language = as it is described in the standard, or as in this case, the only canonical source available in the 1980s. If questions about the language (de facto) standard are not ok, then I don't know what is.

Comment: *"If questions about the language (de facto) standard are not ok"* - I've not said anything that implies that. For one thing, I agree a tag about the book should exist. For another, as I understand your own description of what the tags mean, questions about K&R *taken as a standard* ought to be tagged `kr-c` and not `kernigan-and-ritchie`, and the appropriateness of the `kr-c` tag is not the topic of the question. And for another, you're still conflating the appropriateness of a tag existing with the acceptability of the questions covered by the tag, when these two things are distinct.

Comment: @MarkAmery Examples: a question about why the hello world example in the book (which is _the_ hello world example) crashes when executed should be tagged [tag:kernighan-and-ritchie], while a question about the meaning of the code `func(a,b) int a; { ... }` should be tagged [tag:kr-c].

Comment: Surprised to see you say *unfortunately* in "...K&R book, which is (unfortunately) frequently used by beginners still to this day."

Comment: @kjhughes It's a horrible and outdated book that's why. I'd rather have beginners reading good books. Regardless, this is not the place to discuss the quality of the book itself.

Comment: Since August there is a synonym from [tag:kr-c] to [tag:kernigham-and-ritchie]. That really hurts.

Comment: Is all the code in the book written in the "KR C" version of C? If so, why do we need a separate tag for the book, especially if non-book questionss about KR C are exceedingly rare as you say? Why not just mention in the body of the question that your question is about a code snippet from the K&R book? As for 'questions about the standard', we don't typically have tags just for standards _works_... we have tags for the language, or version-specific tags, at most, which encompass questions about their respective standards.