# Why are my edits which add the "kernighan-and-ritchie" tag to relevant questions being rejected?

Tags: discussion, tags, rejected-edits

I have recently been adding some (half a dozen or more) [kernighan-and-ritchie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kernighan-and-ritchie) tags to questions about K&R (2e), that is: *The C Programming Language* (2nd ed; Kernighan & Ritchie). A lot of people still read this book, and adding a respective tag will make it easier to locate questions about it.

Yet, *many or most* of them got summarily dismissed (most recently (I strictly only added the tag there): [1](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/34733177), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/34733175), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/34733173)), with the reason being indicated as:

> The edit does not improve the quality of the post. Changes to the content are unnecessary or make the post more confusing.

[In one case](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/34661140) I even added a reference to K&R to an obscure code snippet, to provide context for inquisitive readers, so that they would be able to know where it came from. (Source attribution ought to be a good thing.) Yet, the same reviewers rejected the edit, with one even choosing

> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post.

as the reason for rejection.

It seems to me that these rejections come from the same small group of reviewers, and I believe that these rejections are overeager (the reviewers in question appear to have a high rejection rate) and not appropriate. But I am open to being convinced otherwise.

Why can't I add relevant tags and side information to questions? Also, the respective questions seemed to have decent scores as well as answers, so it's not like I was editing meaningless posts.

Comment: *"I believe that these rejections are overeager (the reviewers in question appear to have a high rejection rate)"* - You'd be surprised how many bad suggested edits there are. There is nothing wrong with having a high reject rate.

Comment: @Nickistired Acknowledged (but I'm still confused). Btw, should I add some links to questions where my respective tag edits were rejected, or is this post of mine sufficiently clear / self-contained?

Comment: I think replacing the existing link to the post with a link [to the suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/34661140) would help somewhat, but at the same time I had no issue understanding the issue, so I don't mind either way.

Comment: My first instinct: the book isn't a tool, it's just reference information, and it doesn't specify a variant or implementation of the language. So we shouldn't really be having questions about what the book says in the first place. That said, I'm [pre-disagreed with](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365267/).

Comment: I had a look at example 1. My question is: *how does knowing* that the code comes from that book *help to understand or answer the question*? OP titled it that way, but it's clearly a bad title per the guidelines in [ask].

Comment: @KarlKnechtel It doesn't really matter how someone came to a question, it only matters if it is on-topic or not. So questions about what a book says are fine. But I wonder why there is a tag about authors of a book and not the book itself? And even if the tag were named after the book ... do we need that as a tag?

Comment: @Tom "why there is a tag about authors of a book and not the book itself?" - the tag is about the book. "Kernighan and Ritchie", shortened to "K&R", is how programmers commonly refer to that book - similar to how they say "The Dragon book", rather than "*Compilers: Principles, Techniques and Tools*, by Aho, Sethi & Ullman".

Comment: For [2](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/34733175) and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/34733173) I'd maybe suggest that the reason is because the edit doesn't address other problems in the question; you don't remove the "thanks", the "edit" sub heading, and other noise. Just adding the tag isn't helpful when there's other things that should be addressed too.

Comment: (*K&R* = *[The C Programming Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language)*. (Red) Dragon book = *[Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools)* (*"The first edition (1986) is informally called the "red dragon book" to distinguish it from the second edition"*). [A sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66891948). Another common one is ***GoF*** (or *Gang of Four*) book  = *[Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns)*.)

Comment: *It seems to me that these rejections come from the same small group of reviewers*. Yes, this small group is called "The ONLY reviewers".

Answer (score 15):

I'm guessing these edits get rejected because they don't add any critical information.

In fact, if we test that [kernighan-and-ritchie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kernighan-and-ritchie) tag against the [burnination criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191):

> 1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

I'd say it doesn't. This tag still requires technology-specific tags such as a language or a concept the question is dealing with.

> 2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

No. Books are not a subject on SO.

> 3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

I'd argue it doesn't. It does not matter where a piece of code or a problem comes from. A question should be self-contained, so the fact the problem came from a book is irrelevant.

> 4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

Kinda, *"It's related to this book"*, but that information is meaningless, see point 3.

---

Frankly, I think the entire tag adds no value to SO, and might as well be burninated.

Comment: As I noted in the question comments, there is [precedent to overturn](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365267/) on this very tag. However, I agree with you.

Comment: Well, if the tag is being sanctioned by SO (as of now) and its very purpose is to index questions about the book, then that ought to override more general considerations. Also, people (for better or for worse) still read this book, a lot, so such indexing adds value.

Comment: I just followed the "burnination criteria" link – the criteria you listed are basically about the tag itself, not about whether an edit should be approved or rejected.

Comment: @LoverofStructure - Just because the tag was created doesn’t mean it’s sanctioned by SO. Furthermore the point about the burnination of the tag, if the tag should be deleted, then adding it makes the edit a trivial edit that should be rejected. I agree with the edit rejecting, your edits you shared, added nothing of substance and wouldn’t make it easier to find the questions or answer them.

Comment: @SecurityHound The discussion [here about that tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/365267/2057969) certainly suggests that the SO community approves of the tag. Perhaps my wording "sanctioned by SO" was vague, but that lies in the vagueness of what policy and community consensus mean to begin with, and either way, the tag has existed for a while and been discussed, so the contrapositive certainly holds: if the tag is seen as insubstantial, the tag should be burninated, but respective edits shouldn't be rejected as of now. (And, I do think the tag is useful, but that's obvious from my post.)

Comment: @LoverofStructure - Regardless if the tag should or shouldn’t exist simply adding a tag without any other substantial edits is typical frowned upon. The addition of the tag to those questions would not make them easier to find in order to answer them. All of the questions were answered years ago.

Comment: @SecurityHound Is it? (Was this discussed on Meta?) I see it being done a lot for new questions by beginners who don't really know how to tag.

Comment: @LoverofStructure - New questions without answers? How about nearly decade old questions? Is someone really going to be able to provide a new answer to those 4 questions, asked 8+ years ago, with an answer to a question about code from a book. Which means it literally has a “book answer”.

Comment: @SecurityHound Another perspective is this: Perhaps someone wants to browse through questions about the book, while reading through the book.

Comment: @SecurityHound There is, while we're at it, a question about the solution manual without a correct answer (I just haven't gotten along to posting mine yet, but will do so in the foreseeable future), and I've recently discovered a previously undocumented semantic mistake in K&R. I don't *adore* the book like some do, though, and I'm growing increasingly aware of it's deficiencies. // If you click on the tag on SO, there are lots of questions about the book – enough that the tag matters, and yet not as many as to cause someone to not be able to read through them all.

Comment: @LoverofStructure here's my thoughts, [so] is about finding answers to programming questions not about finding answers to questions you have about a programming book. A good question asks about the programming concept / problem directly rather than asking about the book. Adding tags for specific books will distract from that and reduce the question quality (since it throws focus on the book). If you look at the posts you edited none of them actually had a **good title**

Comment: This is why I don't like bending the rules to solve a problem. It creates dissonance. To me this falls into the same category as the long list of C++ book recommendations. We don't do recommendations, so you don't do such a list on Stack Overflow. Even if it worked okay for a long time because people were guarding it like it was their own property. It is only a matter of time until someone tries to copy the idea, it is rejected and the finger pointing starts.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Adding a tag objectively improves search; it doesn't visually distract in the post's body. As for mentioning K&R in my 4th example's post body: it's about proper citation (and about providing context, as that question's line of code might be confusing outside of context).

Comment: Proper citation doesn't require that tag.

Comment: @Cerbrus My edit in that case was not limited to adding the tag; it included addition of a citation and was rejected.

Comment: That [4th example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339569/is-casting-free-argument-to-void-neccessary) has ___no___ mention of that book ___anywhere___. Who are you to assume that book is even relevant, @LoverofStructure?

Comment: @Cerbrus We're going in circles – (1) It's reasonable to consider the possibility that the answer depends on material that wasn't cited. (2) Casting to `void *` before `free`ing is unnecessary and stylistically odd, unless you're trying to explicitly discard `const`ness. The origin of that style however is likely K&R (which incidentally apply this style in many but not all of their cases, without clear consistency).

Comment: @LoverofStructure People don't come to [so] to search for questions about a book, they are searching for answers to a **programming question**. Tell me if you really believe those questions you edited are searchable from a search engine without using the name of the book and can be searched by describing the problem / question instead.

Comment: @LoverofStructure: _"It's reasonable to consider the possibility..."_ Sure, I agree, but that doesn't mean you should turn that possibility into _fact_ by editing it into the question. You're acting based on assumptions, rather than proof.

Comment: @LoverofStructure that single line of code you are trying to cite the source of could have come from anywhere, it probably falls under fair use even if it did come from the book. Editing that in unnecessarily doesn't seem like a good edit to me.

Comment: @Cerbrus For ex4, in the line in question (`free((void *) np->defn);`), `np->defn` could conceivably be `const`. Hence, whether the cast to `void *` is necessary technically depends on how the struct `np` is defined. In that question, everyone just assumes, but when reading that post, one is wondering whether the questioner's words "`defn` is a `char *`" really imply that it's not a `const char *`. For an answerer to check is prudent, and the reference to K&R in this case an improvement. (Abdul: I don't think anyone *actually* doubts this specific line is from K&R, after this is pointed out.)

Comment: @LoverofStructure none of that changes that you're adding information to a question based on an ___assumption___. Don't do that.

Comment: I dunno, I mean...it's not an unreasonable assumption given the _exact_ match and lack of any other context.  And in fact, it's a provably correct one: [the author confirmed it in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339569/is-casting-free-argument-to-void-neccessary#comment39505694_25339590), in a way that implies that the fact that it was in that book is what motivated their question.

Comment: Separately... does it actually change the meaning of the question in this case to add a well-known context for that code snippet to it that might make it easier to find for readers of a _very_ well-known reference?  (this is a genuine question; I am not at all familiar with C)